# AlmostEqual2sComplement implementation not handling degenerated cases

Tags: c++, floating-point, comparison

I implemented the AlmostEqual2sComplement as proposed by [Bruce Dawson](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm), but for comparing double instead of float values.

Similar implementations can be found in many places.

```
bool AlmostEqual2sComplement(double A, double B, int maxUlps= 10)
{
    // Make sure maxUlps is non-negative and small enough that the
    // default NAN won't compare as equal to anything.
    // assert maxUlps > 0 && maxUlps < 4 * 1024 * 1024;

    long long aInt = *(long long*)&A;
    // Make aInt lexicographically ordered as a twos-complement int
    if (aInt < 0)
        aInt = 0x8000000000000000 - aInt;

    // Make bInt lexicographically ordered as a twos-complement int
    long long bInt = *(long long*)&B;
    if (bInt < 0)
        bInt = 0x8000000000000000 - bInt;

    long long intDiff = aInt - bInt;
    if (intDiff < 0)
        intDiff= intDiff*-1;

    if (intDiff <= maxUlps)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Unfortunately when comparing the double value -1.0 and 4.0 the function returns true.
This is because the intDiff results in this case to be equal `0x8000000000000000` and 
the absolute value of `0x8000000000000000` is again `0x8000000000000000`

My current solution to this problem is not to take the absolute value of intDiff but rather change the comparision of intDiff and maxUlps to:

```
if (intDiff <= maxUlps && -maxUlps <= intDiff)
    return true;
```

There must be more (maybe not so evident) cases where intDiff results in `0x8000000000000000`.

I'm wondering if other implementations of AlmostEqual2sComplement are just not aware of this problem, or if I made a mistake in my original implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition is the corrected version, where there is an additional check whether the two floats have opposite sign.

Comment: Thank you, great. This solves the problem! Since the intDiff can never produce underflow if the signs aInt and bInt are equal.